# How can I provide an Index Hint to a MS-SQL Server Indexed View?

Tags: sql-server-2012, non-clustered-index, indexed-view

I have an indexed view `FooView`.

I've created the following indexes against it:

- `CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Foo1 ON [FooView](SomeId, AnotherId)`
- `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Foo2 ON [FooView](SomeId)`

Is it possible to use a HINT against `IX_Foo2` ? It keeps using `IX_Foo1` when I use the `WITH (NOEXPAND)` hint.

Comment: Did you try adding an index hint along with the `noexpand`? If so what happened?

Comment: What's an example of that, syntax wise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is perfectly straightforward

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.FooTable
  (
     SomeId    INT,
     AnotherId INT,
     Filler    CHAR(8000)
  );

go

CREATE VIEW dbo.FooView
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  SELECT SomeId,
         AnotherId,
         Filler
  FROM   dbo.FooTable

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Foo1
  ON dbo.FooView(SomeId, AnotherId)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Foo2
  ON dbo.FooView(SomeId)

GO

SELECT SomeId
FROM   dbo.FooView WITH (noexpand) --No hint non clustered index chosen automatically

SELECT *
FROM   dbo.FooView WITH (noexpand) --No hint clustered index chosen automatically

SELECT *
FROM   dbo.FooView WITH (noexpand, INDEX = IX_Foo2) --With hint nonclustered index forced
```

**Execution plans**

(Note that forcing the index with a hint led to a more expensive plan than leaving the choice up to the optimiser though)

[image]

Comment: Side note @MartinSmith - I have the same situation when I force the hint (instead of it using the cluster index chosen automatically) ... it was less performant AND wanting to do that Key Lookup :(